# Why strdup and strcat combination is not working in linux android ndk

Tags: android, linux, string, visual-studio-2012, android-ndk

Consider the following code. The task at hand is to concatenate "Primary" and "_Secondary._tcp.local" into "Primary._Secondary._tcp.local"

The value of `fqdn_global` should be `Primary._Secondary._tcp.local`
I tried following code. But the output is not as expected.

```
char *serviceName ;//= "_TestImpl._tcp.local";
char *fqdn_global ;//= "MyTestPc._TestImpl._tcp.local";
char *targetName  ;//= "MyTestPc.local";
jint Java_com_example_basicndk1_Ndk1Activity_sendAnnouncement(JNIEnv* env,
        jobject javaThis,jstring lServiceType,jstring lServiceName) {
    char *implName,*implNameWithDot;
    r = 0;
    serviceName = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, lServiceType,NULL);
    LOGI("serviceName %s",serviceName);
    implName = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, lServiceName,NULL);
    LOGI("implName %s",implName);
    implNameWithDot = strdup(implName);
    LOGI("implNameWithDot %s @%p",implNameWithDot,implNameWithDot);
    strcat(implNameWithDot,".");
    LOGI("implNameWithDot %s @%p",implNameWithDot,implNameWithDot);
    fqdn_global = strdup(implNameWithDot);
    LOGI("fqdn_global %s",fqdn_global);
    strcat(fqdn_global,serviceName);
    LOGI("fqdn_global %s",fqdn_global);
    targetName = strdup(implName);
    LOGI("fqdn_global %s",fqdn_global);
    strcat(targetName,".local");
//  LOGI("fqdn_global %s",fqdn_global);
    LOGI("targetName %s",targetName);
//  LOGI("fqdn_global %s",fqdn_global);
    LOGI("announcing \n%s\n%s\n%s",fqdn_global,serviceName,targetName);
    LOGI("mdns_resp_announce returned %d",r);
err:
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, lServiceType, serviceName);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, lServiceName, implName);
}
```

Its output is

```
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): serviceName _Sec._tcp.local
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): implName Pri
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): implNameWithDot Pri @0x588d8208
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): implNameWithDot Pri. @0x588d8208
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): fqdn_global Pri.
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): fqdn_global Pri._Sec._tcp.local
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): fqdn_global Pri._Sec._tc
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): targetName Pri.local
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): announcing 
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): Pri._Sec._tc
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): _Sec._tcp.local
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): Pri.local
03-30 18:30:10.494: I/compat.h(18392): mdns_resp_announce returned 0
```

Similarly I tried the same in Cygwin GNU C Still same problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//typedef char uint8_t;
#define LOGE printf
#define LOGI LOGE
int r;
char *serviceName ;//= "_TestImpl._tcp.local";
char *fqdn_global ;//= "MyTestPc._TestImpl._tcp.local";
char *targetName  ;//= "MyTestPc.local";
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    char *implName,*implNameWithDot;
    r = 0;
    serviceName = argv[1];//(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, lServiceType,NULL);
    LOGI("serviceName %s\n",serviceName);
    implName = argv[2];//(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, lServiceName,NULL);
    LOGI("implName %s\n",implName);
    implNameWithDot = strdup(implName);
    LOGI("implNameWithDot %s @%p\n",implNameWithDot,implNameWithDot);
    strcat(implNameWithDot,".");
    LOGI("implNameWithDot %s @%p\n",implNameWithDot,implNameWithDot);
    fqdn_global = strdup(implNameWithDot);
    LOGI("fqdn_global %s\n",fqdn_global);
    strcat(fqdn_global,serviceName);
    LOGI("fqdn_global %s\n",fqdn_global);
    targetName = strdup(implName);
    LOGI("fqdn_global %s\n",fqdn_global);
    strcat(targetName,".local");
//  LOGI("fqdn_global %s",fqdn_global);
    LOGI("targetName %s\n",targetName);
//  LOGI("fqdn_global %s",fqdn_global);
    LOGI("announcing \n%s\n%s\n%s",fqdn_global,serviceName,targetName);

}
```

### The output is

```
serviceName _Secondary._tcp.local
implName Primary
implNameWithDot Primary @0xf58270
implNameWithDot Primary. @0xf58270
fqdn_global Primary.
fqdn_global Primary._Secondary._tcp.local
fqdn_global Primary._Sec
targetName Primary.local
announcing 
Primary._Sec
_Secondary._tcp.local
Primary.local
```

But the above code works in Visual Studio 2012 compiler as expected.

Comment: `strdup()` allocates storage, `strcat()` does not.  If you add characters to a `strdup()`-allocated string with `strcat()`, you may write past the end of the allocated block, and the behavior is undefined.  Allocate your strings manually, or use a `string` object.

Comment: Thanks fadden, But how does it working in MSVC compiler ? Any comment on that ?

Comment: Different implementations of libc have different heap allocation strategies. It's possible the msvcrt malloc() is using a different chunk size or placement, and so it happens to work without apparent failure. I expect that, if you enable a heap-checker in MSVC, you will see complaints.